# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return BlocConsumer<HomeCubit,HomeState>(
            listener:(context ,state) {},
            builder:(context ,state){
              var media = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
              var cubit = HomeCubit.get(context);
              List imageUrls = [
                'htthttps://nowfoods.is/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/a9eb495d-187f-46d4-8a41-9808034a0922.pngps://example.com/image1.jpg',
                'htthttps://nowfoods.is/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/a9eb495d-187f-46d4-8a41-9808034a0922.pngps://example.com/image1.jpg',
                'htthttps://nowfoods.is/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/a9eb495d-187f-46d4-8a41-9808034a0922.pngps://example.com/image1.jpg',
                // Add more image URLs as needed
              ];
              if(cubit.homeItems.isNotEmpty && state is Sucesssssssssssss){
                return  Scaffold(
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.red,)),
                                const Text('مرحبا',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: CarouselSlider(
                              items: imageUrls.map((e){
                                return e;
                              }).toList(),
                              options: CarouselOptions(
                                viewportFraction:1,
                                padEnds: false,
                                enlargeCenterPage: false, // Center item is larger
                                autoPlay: true, // Auto play the carousel
                                autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5), // Auto play interval
                                autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), // Animation duration
                                enableInfiniteScroll: true, // Infinite scrolling
                                initialPage: 0, // Initial page index
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ListView.separated(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemBuilder: (ctx,i){
                                return buildItems(
                                  cubit.homeItems[i].shape,
                                  cubit.homeItems[i],
                                  ctx
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (ctx,i){
                                return SizedBox(height: 5,);
                              },
                              itemCount: cubit.homeItems.length
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            } ,
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is because the `CarouselSlider.items` property expects a list of Widgets, but you are giving it a list of Strings.

To fix this, you can use the `Image.network()` widget to convert the image URLs to Widgets.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
List imageUrls = [
  'https://example.com/image1.jpg',
  'https://example.com/image2.jpg',
  'https://example.com/image3.jpg',
];

CarouselSlider(
  items: imageUrls.map((imageUrl) {
    return Image.network(imageUrl);
  }).toList(),
  options: CarouselOptions(
    viewportFraction: 1,
    padEnds: false,
    enlargeCenterPage: false,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
    autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
    initialPage: 0,
  ),
),
```

This will convert the list of image URLs to a list of Image widgets, which the CarouselSlider can then display.